How do I see the contents of the git repository in Visual Studio 2022?
As a TFVC veteran, I'm trying to move to Git due to decision from above. I managed to create a repository on DevOps, clone it on my machine (attempting to merely "connect" to it had no effect) and even commit and push changes, but I can't find a way to view the repository's contents from Visual Studio.
the Team Explorer gives me two buttons "Git Changes" and "Git Repository", but the latter, instead of showing me the file tree on the repository, only shows me what seems to be a history.

I'm not clear on what you want to see in Visual Studio's Git implementation, but I think you are looking for a way to view the entire Git Repository file tree history for a given commit.  I'm unsure if native Visual Studio has a way to do that.  There is an extension for Git Extensions here which you can install via the extension manager. I personally use the standalone Git Extensions desktop application which does offer a way to view full file tree history, so I assume the extension does as well.

@TimothyG. I'm simply looking for the Git equivalent of the Source Control Explorer. You know, the thing that shows the current contents of the repository file tree (the central one, not the local one).

Yea - looking at what "Source Control Explorer" is (I never used Team Foundations), it seems similar to what I said with Git Extensions.  Here is what it looks like in the Standalone Desktop Git Extensions Application https://i.sstatic.net/ATgi7.png I am assuming the VIsual Studio extension has something similar, but I've never checked/used it.

So I need this extension for it? I'm highly disappointed (this seems like part of the minimal feature set to me, so it's a glaring omission) but thanks.

To be clear, I'm not even sure if the extension has what you need. I'm just guessing it does. The default git experience in Visual Studio I never liked. I do all of my git operations outside of it.

You have cloned the repository to your local machine, so if you navigate to the path at which you cloned the repository in (presumably Windows) File Explorer you will be able to explore the files in the repo.
If you specifically want to see all the files from Visual Studio, you could use:
File > Open > Folder > (your local git repo)
Then the Solution Explorer in folder view will show you the files in your repository.

But only the local version. I have not found a way to observe the shared version from within Visual Studio; the best I have found involves using a web browser to check the repository on Azure Devops through the Azure Devops website (which is highly impractical).

I have no experience of TFVC and I don't know your experience with Git, so apologies if this comes across as condescending in any way as I don't mean it to be.
The local version is the shared version, it's just a snapshot of whenever you last pulled from the repo. If you want to update your local copy to see the latest changes then you can just use the git pull command (assuming you don't have any local uncommitted changes). If you just want to view the repository without pulling then you'll have to use the web browser. That's how it works with other remote repository sites such has GitHub.

I am new to Git and trying to learn use it with Visual Studio and VS Code. I was looking for the same view you are referring to, because I think VS Code has the feature to observe the folder structure. I think the most equivalent view in Visual Studio for observing the folder structure can be found under Solution Explorer and selecting "Show all files" from the top bar.

I don't have VS Code handy to test, but I suspect it will only show the local repository.
